# What are the subjects and predicates of the clauses in "There is the mountain that we are going to climb."?

Tags: clauses, parsing

What would be the subjects and the predicates of the following sentence:

> **There is the mountain** *that we are going to climb*.

Independent clause: There is the mountain

Dependent clause: that we are going to climb.

Would "there" or "mountain" be the subject of the independent clause?
Would "that" or "we" be the subject of the dependent clause?
And what are the predicates?

Answer (score -1):

There are various definitions of "subject" and "predicate", but in most traditional grammars, the subject of the sentence would be "the mountain that we are going to climb" and the predicate would be "there is". Note that the simple subject is "mountain", which is modified by the relative clause "that we are going to climb". Being a clause, it has its own subject ("we") and predicate ("that . . . are going to climb").